# Configurar wampserver para enviar email de manera local

Tags: php, email, wamp

estoy intentando enviar un email desde un sistema web de manera local, el problema es que al intentar mandar el correo electrónico no recibo nada, ya hice una configuración previa con SENDEMAIL, pero sigue sin funcionar, no se cual es el problema.

Este es mi archivo Envio.php, en donde tengo los datos que quiero enviar:

```
<?php
$to = "enrique@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: enriqueespinosaRE@outlook.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

este es el archivo SENDMAIL.ini:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=prueba@gmail.com
auth_password=contraseña

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost:8000
```

y estos son los cambios que tengo en el php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="prueba@gmail.com"

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

No se si me falte una configuración o algo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Prueba con este tuto a ver: [TUTORIAL](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/aporte-enviar-e-mail-desde-server-local-1132832/), yo realice eso con stunnel

Comment: Prueba a quitar las comillas en los datos que has modificado en php.ini